# Conditionally select log providers with systemd

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, .net-core, systemd

My ASP.NET Core 3.1 application used to log to the console only. Now I've added systemd integration. Next I'm using a [third-party package to enhance the logging to the journal](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tmds.Systemd.Logging). The problem is, the application must work both in systemd and in the Windows console for development. If I add both providers, I get duplicate log entries in Linux/systemd.

How can I conditionally select the log provider if systemd was found?

```cs
private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSystemd()
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                if (__isSystemd__)
                {
                    logging.AddJournal(options =>
                    {
                        options.SyslogIdentifier = "myapp";
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    logging.AddConsole();
                }
            });
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
}
```

I found out that `UseSystemd` [adds a service](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/Systemd/src/SystemdHostBuilderExtensions.cs) that I could test for. But I can't get hold of something that would tell me about already registered services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of digging around, I found one solution, and then a better one. These go where my question says `if (__isSystemd__)`.

#1:

```cs
if (logging.Services.Any(s => s.ImplementationType == typeof(SystemdLifetime)))
{
    // add journal logging
}
```

#2:

```cs
if (SystemdHelpers.IsSystemdService())
{
    // add journal logging
}
```

The `SystemdHelpers` class comes from the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd package that also provides [`UseSystemd`](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/Systemd/src/SystemdHostBuilderExtensions.cs). It caches its decision in a static variable so it's probably the quickest option. It also uses this very information to determine whether to do all the systemd stuff (like registering the `SystemdLifetime` service that cares about notification).